# Codeigniter PHP time constraint

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating a article sharing application using Codeigniter PHP. Every article has a 3 text boxes including name,email and comment. Now I need to block comments that come within 1 minute of the previous comment by the same user.How can I do so? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please show us what you have at the moment. Nobody can comment on anything with no background information.

Comment: where is your tried code

Comment: I have 3 textboxes with name,email and comment-msg in my view. I use this->input-> post() in my controller to  get the 3 values and store and retrieve from database.Now when the same person comments again within 1 minute, I need to block his comment and possibly exception saying he needs to wait certain more seconds to comment again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a timestamp last_updated field for each user ( as it's user related, and not each comment related ), and then select last update_time for that user, then compare and look if the time is less than the period you want, in this case a minute.

If the constraint is not critical, you can also control this by javascript in the client ( having the same mark variable, and comparing the time elapsed from the last update ).

For php:

```
$last_update = $db->get_var("select last_updated from time_comments where user_id='$uid'");

$elapsed = time() - $last_update;

if($elapsed < 60){
   echo 'cannot comment';
}

//process comment
```